# Create Accounting for Internet and merge ADSL, is there any way?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, vlan

I have 4 Simple Wireless ADSL Modem that 4MB, 8MB, 16MB, 40MB Internet BW.

I have one HP Server with 4 Network Ethernet Ports.

I have 7 LAN based PC's, 2 Network Printer and some wireless station such as mobile, tablets.

My question is what is the efficient way to merge this ADSLs and create some VLAN and distribute user on VLANS and create accounting system for using Internet? (Tips: I virtualized server as 4 virtual machine)

Comment: What is your goal?  If you want to combine bw, you should get one big connection.  If you want to allocate bandwidth and charge for it, it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @RonTrunk at first accounting system and bandwidth management  for users, second combines 4 ADSL.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve your somewhat hazy goals. However, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as on most SE sites.

Comment: @Zac67 I look for architecture not products

Comment: Assuming you mean load balancing with "merge modems" you'd need a load balancer.

Comment: So You means I buy a load balancer for two goals? @Zac67 would you please describe as an answer with details?

Comment: I can't provide detailed answers for very general questions, see below.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the efficient way to merge this ADSLs

You'll need a load balancer to distribute bandwidth from the WAN uplinks to your users. A load balancer can be a dedicated device or a router/firewall feature. Note that WAN links can't usually be "merged" (as in aggregated), you need to keep the IP traffic separate for each.

> and create some VLAN and distribute user on VLANS

This is a separate venue. You create VLANs on switches, assign your nodes to thse VLANs and use VLAN trunks between networking devices. Usually, you zone your network by geography, security, bandwidth requirements or similar. These zones can be mapped to VLANs which in turn get served by your router(s). Without specifics we can only provide general help.

> and create accounting system for using Internet?

Another venue. Without specific questions we won't be able to help you. Again, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Accounting system can be provided by routers for accounting and BW managment?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of routers/firewalls around for that - depending on your requirements that you didn't tell us.